# sourceText value through script

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

Any idea why below two lines are not being executed in After Effects?
In first line, I simply want to show source text value through an alert.
In second line, I want to select layer number with index value of 2.

```
alert(app.project.activeItem.layer(2).sourceText.value)

app.project.activeItem.layer(2).selected = true;
```

I am getting Undefined error in console.
Both seem to be very basic tasks but I am not being able to figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To access the text document value of text layer you need to call it in this way:

```
var textDocument = app.project.activeItem.layer(2).text.sourceText.value;
```

Then to get the value of the text document (the actual text) you need to get the text property:

```
var text = textDocument.text;
```

The text  document object contains (almost) all properties of the text layer.

The 2nd line should work properly. Probably it didn't fired because the script failed on the 1st line.

If you want to deselect all layers before, you need to loop all the selected layers and deselect them. You can do it with this code:

```
var comp = app.project.activeItem;
var selectedLayers = comp.selectedLayers;
for (var i = 0; i < selectedLayers.length; i++) {
    selectedLayers[i].selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ziki, I am trapped in some loop related complexity. I have some actions on selected layers which works fine, except for the fact that I want to deselect any layers which were selected before and then it should select only the layer with index(2).  
    var myComp = app.project.activeItem;     
    var selectedLayers = myComp.selectedLayers;
    var numLayers = selectedLayers.length;

    for(var i=0; i < numLayers; i++){
       my actions on selected layers go here....
     }
     app.project.activeItem.layer(2).selected = true;

Comment: You'll need to explicitly deselect any layers you don't want selected. Setting the selection to true for a layer doesn't deselect other layers as it would if you clicked with a mouse.

Comment: @SmIqbal Just updated my answer with code to deselect all layers in the comp.

Comment: stib: what you said totally makes sense. Ziki: Thanks for finding me an alternate way of doing this. I am away from my desk for next few hours but will give it a try later today. Thanks again.